# How to use lxml for web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml.html

I want to write a python script that fetches my current reputation on stack overflow --https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483205/raunanza?tab=profile

This is the code I have written.

```
from lxml import html 
import requests
page = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483205/raunanza?tab=profile')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Now, what to do to fetch my reputation. (I can't understand how to use xpath even
after googling it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some modifications in your code to get the xpath. Below is the code:

```
from lxml import HTML 
import requests

page = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483205/raunanza?tab=profile')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 
title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="avatar-card"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/text()')
print(title) #prints 3
```

You can easily get the xpath of element in chrome console(inspect option).
[image]

To learn more about xpath you can refer: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `lxml` and `beautifulsoup`:

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483205/raunanza?tab=profile').text
tree = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
name = tree.find("div", {'class': 'grid--cell fw-bold'}).text
title = tree.find("div", {'class': 'grid--cell fs-title fc-dark'}).text
print("Stackoverflow reputation of {}is: {}".format(name, title))
# output: Stackoverflow reputation of Raunanza is: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `BeautifulSoup`, you can directly extract the text from the tag which contains your reputation. Of course you need to check page structure first.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483205/raunanza?tab=profile')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features= 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all('strong', {'class': 'ml6 fc-medium'}):
    print(tag.text)
#this will output as 3
```